# Best practice for React Native component styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently, setting up a boilerplate code for React Native app development in my company. We're new to React Native and Mobile App development in general, but have a good number of React/JS developer.

I wonder what's the best practice for component styling in React Native out there.
I'm curious to know how you structure your style code and what method do you use for styling.

I look up several articles, there's various opinion on the method between using inline styles, `StyleSheet` component from the core library or using a library such as `StyledComponents`

In terms of code structure, I'm currently split my component into its own folder with `index.js` and `styles.js`. Is this a scalable solution for more components development coming?

Any suggestions or feedback I will really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strongly opinionated response, I use styled components to style my components, I find it very easy and intuitive, also it is easy to achieve styling with SSR. For smaller projects i use vanilla css with className attribute on my JSX. For some quick styles i use the JS object notation with the style attribute.

Comment: I specifically ask for React Native usage. Maybe not applicable in terms of SSR. But thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

I am not using inline CSS. In my opinion, it's not a good practice.

In my project structure go with feature wise. 
As an example, we consider the Login feature

```
login -LoginForm.js
      -Login.container.js
      -Login.stylesheet.js
```

In Login.js you can import the styles from Login.stylesheet.js

```
import st from "./Login.stylesheet"
```

and inside the reusable folder, we maintaining shared.stylesheet as well for some common styles